# Which Hash function is used by AWS Firehose?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, hash, amazon-kinesis, amazon-kinesis-firehose

AWS Firehose produces files in S3 with following pattern:

`2019-12-24-06-36-08-f6bd467b-af73-4408-9f3e-2c248d8c7e7b.gz`

What hash function is used to to create the filename? I'm more interested in the type of the hash (md5, murmur3, etc.) rather than the excact calculation. In other words: I do not want to recalculate it, but would like to repurpose the hash if it with stands up some mathematical characteristics.